# Storing a 64 bit decimal in two 32 bit registers (ASSEMBLY - NASM)

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

So, my task is to read from the keyboard a max **64 bit decimal number**, and to store that number in **two 32 bit registers** (**EDX:EAX**). For reading, I have to use a function called **mio_readchar** (it's from the **mio library**), which reads a character from the keyboard, and stores it in **AL**.

I don't know whether this is an easy task or not, but I couldn't solve it. I would appreciate, if you guys could help me in solving this interesting problem. Thank you all in advance! :D

Comment: libc [`strtoull`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoull) will already return its 64-bit integer result in `edx:eax`, so just pass your string to it.  (Assuming you're making 32-bit code.)  If you have to implement `result = (result*10) + digit - '0'` yourself, you'll have to use add/adc in the multiply and add steps.

Comment: That's very true. And how would I go around writing that number in decimal form? Similarly, I can use mio_writechar to write a char stored in **AL** on the screen.

Comment: Pass it to `printf("%lld\n", my_int64)`, or convert it yourself with extended-precision division by 10.  integer -> string is a separate question from string->integer.

Comment: That's exactly my problem. I don't know how to implement the division. How would I divide it by 10, if my number is stored in 2 registers?

Comment: Then you should [edit] your question.  As written, you're asking the opposite, about reading a string and converting it to a 64-bit integer.  (apparently in 32-bit code, otherwise you just use 64-bit `rax` and split into `edx:eax` at the end.)

Comment: Anyway, look at compiler output from `gcc -O2 -m32` for a function that uses `uint64_t`.  It will probably call an internal gcc helper function for the actual 64-bit extended-precision division, though.

Comment: Well, this is another part, that I have to write :)

Comment: The problem is, that I can't use any external libraries

Comment: For the division part, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285895/tasmhow-to-printout-a-register-pair-dxax-on-screen-after-multiply/.  Instead of dividing by 10, start with dividing `edx:eax` by a large power of 10 so the quotient won't overflow `eax`.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I'll try :D

Comment: One of the "related" questions in the sidebar has an int64 -> string function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22601155/print-64-bit-number-stored-in-edxeax-to-standard-out

Answer (score 2):

Break it into smaller (simpler) pieces:

- Set the current result to zero
- Get character from keyboard, check if character is valid (e.g. '0' to '9' and not something crazy like 'A'), then subtract '0' from it (so that you get a number from 0 to 9)
- Check if you can multiply the current result by 10 without causing an overflow; then multiply the current result by 10
- Check if you can add the new digit to the current result without causing an overflow; then add the new digit to the current result
- Jump back to the second step (get the next character)

*Note: What causes this loop to stop (enter key?), and what happens in various error conditions, is something for you to figure out.*

Comment: I have the same exact scheme in my mind, but the part with checking if it overflows is giving me trouble

Comment: I successfully solved reading in and writing out a 32 bit decimal, hexadecimal, binary number, I even worked with strings, but this is something different, and it's giving me a lot of headache :)

Comment: @EliezerBeczi: If the current result is greater than `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF/10` (or greater than `0x1999999999999999`) then multiplying by 10 will cause an overflow. For the addition, it's easier to check the carry flag after doing the addition (and then restore the old value if the carry flag was set by the addition if you're rejecting any keyboard input that would've caused overflow).

Comment: @EliezerBeczi: Note that there's multiple ways to handle errors - you can return some sort of status code to the caller (e.g. `0 = OK, 1 = overflow, 2 = bad character), you can display an error message and return a "error/no error" status flag to the caller, (for interactive user input only) you can ignore bad characters and digits that would cause overflow (e.g. so cursor doesn't move and maybe with a "warning beep" so the user knows the character wasn't permitted), etc. It probably doesn't matter which method you use; as long as you don't fail to do checks and return invalid data instead.