# How can I extract the upper 32 bits and lower 32 bits of a 64 bit integer in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers

I want to separate the upper and lower half of a 64 bit integer and put them into two registers.

Comment: This is a duplicate many times over, but `uint32_t lower = bignum & 0xffffffff, upper = bignum >> 32;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store a 64 bit integer in two 32 bit integers and convert back again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810280/how-to-store-a-64-bit-integer-in-two-32-bit-integers-and-convert-back-again) or [How to combine two 32-bit integers into one 64-bit integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768890/how-to-combine-two-32-bit-integers-into-one-64-bit-integer)

Comment: I know that you have to shift the bits in C, but I can only shift it in registers in assembly, and the registers can only hold 32 bits, so I am not sure how I can get the lower 32 bits.

Comment: What assembler/hardware are you using. If you have only 32-bit registers and a 64-bit number - it is already split between two registers. Is this for ARM or x86? See [Storing a 64 bit decimal in two 32 bit registers (ASSEMBLY - NASM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47241503/storing-a-64-bit-decimal-in-two-32-bit-registers-assembly-nasm) and [Accessing and Modifying Upper Bits in x86 and x64 Registers](http://dsasmblr.com/accessing-and-modifying-upper-half-of-registers/)

Comment: Look at C compiler output for a function that takes a uint64_t arg and returns the high or low half.

Comment: Here is Peter's other answer I was looking for [How do I atomically move a 64bit value in x86 ASM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48046591/how-do-i-atomically-move-a-64bit-value-in-x86-asm)

Comment: I am using the intel assembly

Answer (score 2):

Your question is really not clear. You should at least state whether you are using x86 or x64, and whether the source is in a register or in memory.

**From a variable in memory**

```
        ; .u64 --> EDI:ESI
.u64    DQ      0x0123456789ABCDEF
        MOV     ESI, [.u64]
        MOV     EDI, [.u64 + 4]
```

**x64, from a register**

```
        ; RBX --> EDI:ESI
        MOV     ESI, EBX
        MOV     RDI, RBX
        SHR     RDI, 32
```

**x86, from a pair of registers**

```
        ; 64-bit numbers are stored in register pairs, usually EDX:EAX
        ; EDX:EAX --> EDI:ESI
        MOV     EDI, EDX
        MOV     ESI, EAX
```

Comment: Your last example is copying EDX:EAX to ESI:EDI not EDI:ESI.  (i.e. it swaps high/low halves, like a rotate by 32).

Comment: Also note that your x86-64 example doesn't need to `mov esi, ebx`, you can just comment that the low half is available in `ebx`.  With BMI2, you can `rorx rdi, rbx, 32` to get the high half into EDI if you don't need it zero-extended to 64-bit either.

Comment: @Peter Cordes Thanks for pointing out the careless mistake. I made the correction. For your second comment, it really depends on whether `ESI` will be modified or not. If so, the whole `RBX` will be destroyed.

Comment: Right, you extract the high half *first*, then you can use EBX for the low half.  But yeah, if you need the halves zero-extended, you do need mov.  You could `mov esi, ebx` / `shr rbx, 32` to turn RBX into EBX:ESI if you don't need to preserve the original RBX.